# Removing Single Quotes from a String Stored in an Array

Tags: python, regex

I wrote code to append a json response into a list for some API work I am doing, but it stores the single quotes around the alphanumerical value I desire. I would like to get rid of the single quotes. Here is what I have so far:

```
i = 0
deviceID = []

while i < deviceCount:
    deviceID.append(devicesRanOn['resources'][i])
    deviceID[i] = re.sub('[\W_]', '', deviceID[i])
    i += 1
    if i >= deviceCount:
            break
if (deviceCount == 1):

    print ('Device ID: ', deviceID)

elif (deviceCount > 1):
    print ('Device IDs: ', deviceID)
```

the desired input should look like this:

```
input Device IDs:  
['14*************************00b29', '58*************************c3df4']    

Output: 
['14*************************00b29', '58*************************c3df4']

Desired Output: 
[14*************************00b29, 58*************************c3df4]
```

As you can see, I am trying to use RegEx to filter non Alphanumeric and replace those with nothing. It is not giving me an error nor is it preforming the actions I am looking for. Does anyone have a recommendation on how to fix this?

Thank you,
xOm3ga

Comment: Btw. I recommend using `for i in range(deviceCount):`, which does the same as `while i < deviceCount: i += 1`

Comment: Show sample inputs, outputs and desired outputs.

Comment: @hpaulj the examples are shown above

Comment: Looks like you're confusing the quotes that Python puts around strings with actual strings in your data.  If you do something like `deviceList[0].count("'")` (assuming here you have a list of device IDs called `deviceList`) to see if the count is 0 or not.   My guess is there are not any quotes in your data, you're just seeing the quotes that Python puts around strings

Comment: @dblclik that would be highly disconcerting for me then lol, but I will double check

Comment: String elements of a list are always displayed with quotes.

Comment: Change your print statement to `'[{}]'.format(', '.join(deviceID))` to create a single string. You are seeing the way that Python is representing a list of strings and the only way to 'remove' them is to change the representation.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use the default print. You'll need to use your own means of making a representation for the list. But this is easy with string formatting.

```
'[' + ', '.join(f'{id!s}' for id in ids) + ']'
```

The `f'{id:!s}` is an f-string which formats the variable `id` using it's `__str__` method. If you're on a version pre-3.6 which doesn't use f-strings, you can also use

```
'%s' % id
'{!s}'.format(id)
```

PS:

You can simplify you're code significantly by using a list comprehension and custom formatting instead of regexes.

```
ids = [device for device in devicesRanOn['resources'][:deviceCount]]

if deviceCount == 1:
    label = 'Device ID:'
elif deviceCount > 1:
    label = 'Device IDs:'

print(label, '[' + ', '.join(f'{id!s}' for id in ids) + ']')
```